# VBA code to go back to master version of Workbook after creating sub-versions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook which I use as a Master template, that has multiple variations created with different tabs in each one and sent to a different Distribution List.  How can I tell VBA to return to the Master workbook after it saved and sends each 'sub' version?  Here is my code for one of those sub versions:

```
Sub Alignment_Final()
```

'

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False

End With

Sheets(Array("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "CS", "Updates", "Branch Updates", "CS Updates", "Control", "BDE", "Termed BBO", "Alignment")). _
    Select
Sheets("Branch Updates").Activate
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Branch Alignment").Activate
FPath = "C:\Users\mmarshall\Documents\Alignment"
FName = "Alignment" & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName

Call Mail_To_DL

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True

End With

End Sub
```

This works just fine but it leaves me in the new version of the workbook.  I need to return to the Master workbook (called Master Alignment) after this is created and emailed to create more versions with different worksheets in each .  My apologies if this is rudimentary.  I'm running Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define you master workbook to a workbook object in the beginning of you code, you can activate that workbook again later.

Define the master workbook like this (assuming that it is your active workbook when you start running your code):

```
Dim MasterWb As Workbook
Set MasterWb = ActiveWorkbook
```

And then when you want to activate that workbook again, you can do that by:

```
MasterWb.Activate
```